# Finding disjunctive normal form (logic)

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have the following expression

$(P\rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q\rightarrow R) \wedge (R \rightarrow P)$

and I want to create a DNF. I've gotten as far as getting rid of the implication, but I'm not sure how to get to the nice answer Wolfram Alpha gives me:

$(P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (¬P \wedge ¬Q \wedge ¬R) $

When I try to expand things out I just get complicated expressions that I'm not sure how to simplify, and I want to avoid using the truth tables if possible.

Comment: Replace $P\rightarrow Q$ with $Q\vee\lnot P$, etc. and distribute.  Then cancel out terms involving $P\land\lnot P$ etc.

Comment: As I said, the simplification part is where I'm stuck, I don't know how to just cancel those terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the implications with disjunctions, you get
$$
(Q\lor\lnot P)\land(R\lor\lnot Q)\land(P\lor\lnot R)
$$
distributing the first $\land$,
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align*}
&(Q\lor\lnot P)\land(R\lor\lnot Q)\\
&=((Q\lor\lnot P)\land R)\lor((\color{red}{Q}\lor\lnot P)\land\lnot Q)\\
&=(Q\land R)\lor(\lnot P\land R)\lor\cancel{(\color{red}{Q\land\lnot Q})}\lor(\lnot P\land\lnot Q)
\end{align*}
$$
So
$$
\begin{align*}
&(Q\lor\lnot P)\land(R\lor\lnot Q)\land(P\lor\lnot R)\\
&=[(Q\land R)\lor(\lnot P\land R)\lor(\lnot P\land\lnot Q)]\land(P\lor\lnot R)
\end{align*}
$$
and distribute again,
$$
\begin{align*}
&=\{[(Q\land R)\lor(\color{red}{\lnot P}\land R)\lor(\color{red}{\lnot P}\land\lnot Q)]\land P\}\\
&\quad \lor\{[(Q\land\color{red}{R})\lor(\lnot P\land\color{red}{R})\lor(\lnot P\land\lnot Q)]\land\lnot R\}\\
&=[(Q\land R\land P)\lor\cancel{(\color{red}{\lnot P}\land R\land\color{red}{P})}\lor\cancel{(\color{red}{\lnot P}\land\lnot Q\land\color{red}{P})}]\\
&\quad \lor[\cancel{(Q\land\color{red}{R\land\lnot R})}\lor\cancel{(\lnot P\land\color{red}{R\land\lnot R})}\lor(\lnot P\land\lnot Q\land\lnot R)]\\
\end{align*}
$$
leaving precisely
$$
(P\land Q\land R)\lor(\lnot P\land\lnot Q\land\lnot R)
$$
as the DNF.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to self teach so the example was a massive help!